# Ember GroupableMixin by using groupProperty

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to implement GroupableMixin (https://github.com/ahawkins/ember.js/blob/groupable-mixin/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/groupable.js) on EmberJS but I have trouble using it.

I want to specify a groupProperty in my ArrayController (just like how we have sortProperties) and I want my groupings to be calculated based on that property.

---

I did try http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cawaq/3/edit and this is what I got:

```
App.UsersIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['created_at'],
  groupProperty: 'role',
  groupedContent: groupBy('role'), //How do it reference groupProperty in groupBy?
  //How can groupedContent be updated whenever groupProperty is changed?
});
```

I have seen http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-enumerable-no-group-by/3594/6 and http://jsbin.com/ukagip/2/edit but still cannot quite figure out how to make that work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent and behavior of Mr. Hawkins' `GroupableMixin` is very different from the one that's used discussed in Ember's Discourse forum. It seems that you're confusing the two methods.

#### Mixin Approach (a la Mr. Hawkins)

*Note this is the approach I'd recommend*

The `GroupableMixin` is an instance of [`Ember.Mixin`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html), which is used to extend an object's prototype. For a more in depth explanation of mix-in's see [Coding Value's explanation](http://codingvalue.com/blog/emberjs-mix-ins/).

We can determine the mix-ins requirements and behavior from reading the [tests for the mix-in](https://github.com/ahawkins/ember.js/blob/groupable-mix-in/packages/ember-runtime/tests/mix-ins/groupable_test.js):

- the class must behave like an `ArrayProxy` (so ArrayController's are fine)
- a `groupBy` property must be set for the class

So we can include this mix-in in an array controller as follows:

```
App.UsersIndexController  = Ember.ArrayController.extend(Ember.GroupableMixin, {
  groupBy: 'role'
});
```

Now that we've satisfied the mix-in's requirements, we'll have access to a few new computed properties and functions such as `groupedContent` for free. Without adding anything else to the controller, we could write something like this in the template to access the groups:

```
{{#each group in groupedContent}}
  <h1>{{group.name}}</h1>
  <ul>
    {{#each user in content}}
    <li>{{user.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Here's [an example that groups words in an array controller by first letter](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xudex/1/edit).

#### Computed Helper Approach (a la Ember Sherpa)

This method creates a helper which defines a computed property based on the key provided to the function.  We can create a similar function which maps to the group interface of the mix-in:

```
Sherpa = {};
Sherpa.groupBy = function (groupBy) {
    var dependentKey = 'content.@each.' + groupBy;

  return Ember.computed(dependentKey, function(){
    var result = [];

    this.get('content').forEach(function(item){
      var hasGroup = !!result.findBy('name', get(item, groupBy));

      if (!hasGroup) {
        result.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({
          name: get(item, groupBy),
          content: []
        }));
      }

      result.findBy('name', get(item, groupBy)).get('content').pushObject(item);
    });

    return result;
  });
};
```

Now we can use this function to create a `groupedContent` computed property: `groupedContent: Sherpa.groupBy('role')`

Here's [an example which uses the same template as the previous example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xudex/2/edit) and has only swapped the mix-in with this method.

#### Recommendation

Use the `GroupableMixin`, it's far more robust than the method discussed in the forum:

- The method discussed in the forum...

  - is simple and easy to understand
  - is inefficient

    - Recomputes the entire groups array whenever a change is made to the array or relevant property
    - Doesn't implement map structures for lookups and instead searches iteratively through the array
  - Nukes all itemControllers on any computed change: If you check some boxes in the [second example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xudex/2/edit) and then add a new word, all of the checkboxes will be cleared
- The mix-in...

  - is a much more robust, albeit complex, implementation
  - handles inserts and removals to groups instead of recomputing the entire map
  - backs the groups with a map for better performance and efficiency
  - behaves as expected when using an `itemController`: just tick of checkboxes and add some words  in [the first example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xudex/1/edit), and you'll notice that the checkboxes are never cleared